# How can redirect to Home page once a user is logged in?

Tags: reactjs, jwt

How can I redirect to Home page ('/') once a user is **logged in**?

```
async function onHandleSubmit(e: SyntheticEvent) {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (login && password) {
            await fetch('URL/auth/signin', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    "login": login,
                    "password": password
                })
            }).then(response =>
                response.json().then(data => ({
                    data: data,
                })).then(res => {
                    localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
                    localStorage.setItem("userName", res.data.name)
                    localStorage.setItem("avatarUrl", res.data.avatarUrl)
                })
            ).then(() => {
                setLogin('')
                setPassword('')
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `react-router-dom` ?

Comment: @yousoumar, yes

Comment: Saw that someone answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not using redux. You may redirect using React Router Dom as following

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const history = useHistory();
history.push("/dashboard"); // Add this in Then part where Localstorage set.
```